# In JS why the get/set behavior on its prototype's property is different?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, prototype

The derived object can get value of property from its prototype object;
But when set that property ,it will add new property in the derived object.
More see the below code.

```
function Base(name) {this.name  = name };

function Deriver(name) {this.dname  = name };
var base = new Base('base');
Deriver.prototype = base  ;


d1 = new Deriver('d1');
console.log(d1.name);  // it will show "base". That'ok.



d1.name = "new name"; // !!! it does not update the property from its protoype object
                      // it add new property "name" in the object d1. 
console.log(d1.name); // it will show "new name" 
console.log(base.name); // it still show "base"
```

Comment: It puts the property directly on `d1` because that's where you're putting the property. Why would you expect it to put it further down the prototype chain? Properties can shadow properties with the same name further down the chain.

Comment: Hi Crazy, you are right I make wrong question. The question is actually from the comparison inheritance between the C++ and JS.
The inheritance in the C++， the subobject can access properties from base object, both on get and set(of course the public/protected properties). In JS, the subobject only can get the property from prototype object and set will add new property on its local which confuse me a lot. 

 Now I got that the prototype-based inheritance is different to class-based inheritance.    Your question make me think their difference and finally understand it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, and you're right, class-based inheritance is entirely different. The prototypal inheritance is nothing more than a "lookup chain" of objects.